# Programming with Microsoft Kinect

Tags: xbox360, kinect

Does anyone know if an end user purchases the [Kinect sensor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002BSA298), he can program using it to make own games. Or is the API only for professional game studios?

Comment: Related: [What UI Designs are a good fit for the Kinect](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/what-ui-designs-are-a-good-fit-for-the-kinect-primesense-devkit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Link to [MSFT SDK](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/)

**Update:**

Just in from ZD.NET "Microsoft readies hobbyist Kinect development kit; promises commercial version later" [link](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-readies-hobbyist-kinect-development-kit-promises-commercial-version-later/8752)

**Prior Post**

The makers/OEM of the Kinect is PrimeSense.  They make both the kinect and an independent [devkit](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/12/10/primesense-releases-open-source-drivers-middleware-for-kinect/).  They recently released open source drivers that are compatible with both XBox's Kinect and the smaller DevKit.  You might as well get the drivers straight from the source.  I'm not sure what value a 3rd party library (openKinect) will offer.

Get the unified Kinect and DevKit drivers here: http://www.openni.org/  Windows and Unix support is available.

Answer (score 5):

Given that the connection to the [Kinect has been broken open](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2010/11/10/we-have-a-winner-open-kinect-drivers-released-winner-will-use-3k-for-more-hacking-plus-an-additional-2k-goes-to-the-eff/), I'd say anyone can write a game that makes use of it.

Comment: the link here : http://groups.google.com/group/openkinect/browse_thread/thread/f1c5316617ea0e8b , has the data, but its binary and I do not have a player

Answer (score 2):

It's worth bearing in mind that the [current open drivers](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/) are not the official API and 
SDKs from Microsoft.

When it comes to building games for sale on Xbox, Microsoft have pretty stringent testing for Xbox live indy games, so there's no guarantee that any code you write using the unofficial drivers will be supported.

That said, there's another [.NET library for Kinect here](http://nkinect.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

An SDK was announce for a Spring 2011 release at MIX 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Hansel has half on hour show on the subject about the microsoft sdk for kinetic and Kinect Array Microphone.
He interviews Dan Fernandez
Here is a link to the podcast: http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=295